# Как отрефакторить код с приведением типов иерархии классов c проверкой каждого типа через element.GetType == typeof(Class)?

Tags: c#, ооп, list

Хочу сократить количество кода. У меня идет добавление классов в один List<абстрактный класс>, при добавлении все хорошо, при выводе я делаю проверку соответствие экземпляра класса с его изночальным, типом а не цепочкой классов, если делать проверку через is, то мне отдаст true, если класс можно привести к его родителю, а это не то что мне надо. Я сделал проверку, но я пишу лишний код, и думаю что его можно сократить.

```
 if (figure.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in figure)
                {
                    var i = item.GetType();

                    if (i == typeof(Line))
                    {
                        Line line = item as Line;
                        Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
                    }

                    else if (i == typeof(Ring))
                    {
                        Ring ring = item as Ring;
                        Console.WriteLine(ring.ToString());
                    }


                    else if (i == typeof(Square))
                    {
                        Square square = item as Square;
                        Console.WriteLine(square.ToString());
                    }


                    else if (i == typeof(Rectangle))
                    {
                        Rectangle rectangle = item as Rectangle;
                        Console.WriteLine(rectangle.ToString());
                    }


                    else if (i == typeof(Circle))
                    {
                        Circle circle = item as Circle;
                        Console.WriteLine(circle.ToString());
                    }


                    else if (i == typeof(Сircumference))
                    {
                        Сircumference circleWithoutArea = item as Сircumference;
                        Console.WriteLine(circleWithoutArea.ToString());
                    }
                };
            }
```

[image: картинка с иерархией классов]

Comment: ToString можно вызывать без приведения типа, ну и используйте полиморфизм если необходимо

Comment: Я пробую. Но получаю "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.", а разобраться мне удалось уже через пару часов после заданного вопроса.

Comment: @ТимофейБелов слева от вопроса цифра, над ней стрелочка и под ней стрелочка, вы пытаетесь жать на стрелочки. А под нижней стрелочкой - галочка, которую и надо нажать, чтобы отметить ответ принятым. Только один ответ для одного вопроса можно отметить принятым.

Comment: @aepot  сделано!) спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В копилочку, как сократить код.

Фрагмент

```cs
if (i == typeof(Line))
{
    Line line = item as Line;
    Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
}
```

Можно записать вот так с помощью паттерн-матчинга

```cs
if (item is Line line)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

То есть в условии произойдет комбо-действие, одновременно и проверка типа и присваивание значения типизированной переменной. При этом строчка `var i = item.GetType()` становится лишней.

---

Не всегда можно завернуть такое в массив (как в ответе @tym32167, но его вариант по-своему хорош и в некоторых случаях именно он и спасает). К тому же вариант с паттерн-матчингом может оказаться быстрее по производительности, чем `Contains` у массива, но я не проверял.

Проверка `if (figure.Count > 0)` лишняя, цикл `foreach` не будет выполняться, если коллекция пуста.

```cs
foreach (var item in figure)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case Line line:
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            break;
        case Ring ring:
            Console.WriteLine(ring);
            break;
        case Square square:
            Console.WriteLine(square);
            break;
        case Rectangle rectangle:
            Console.WriteLine(rectangle);
            break;
        case Circle circle:
            Console.WriteLine(circle);
            break;
        case Сircumference circleWithoutArea:
            Console.WriteLine(circleWithoutArea);
            break;
    }
}
```

Но это для общего случая, то есть когда в каждом `case` может быть какой-то свой уникальный код. А для вашего конкретного случая код можно написать так:

```cs
foreach (var item in figure)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

---

Почему я убрал `.ToString()`, я предположил, что он у вас переопределен, ну с очень большой вероятностью.

```cs
public override ToString()
{
    // ...
}
```

А `Console.WriteLine()` принимает в себя тип `object`, который неявно наследуют все классы, и для вывода в консоль сам внутри вызыват `object.ToString()`, который у самого `object` является `virtual`. Здесь срабатывает эффект под названием полиморфизм, и отрабатывает именно нужный вам переопределенный метод.

Comment: По идее, можно ещё сократить: `case Line or Ring or Square or Rectangle or Circle or Circumference: Console.WriteLine(item); break;` (в надежде, что никакой из типов не определяет `public new string ToString()`).

Comment: @VladD я пока не пишу ответы на девятом шарпе :)

Comment: Ну тогда я напишу :)

Comment: @VladD свич с одной веткой только можно заменить на `if`.

Comment: Ага, именно так и написал

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
if (figure.Count > 0)
{
    var types = new[] { typeof(Line),typeof(Ring), 
            typeof(Square), typeof(Rectangle), typeof(Circle), typeof(Сircumference) }; 
    
    foreach (var item in figure)
    {
        var type = item.GetType();          
        if (types.Contains(type)) Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());           
    };
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, это хороший вариант!

Comment: если помогло, то галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: к сожалению не могу оставить из за рейтинга низкого.(

Comment: Кстати здесь будет работать и вариант без проверки типов)

Comment: @ТимофейБелов слева от ответа цифра, под цифрой и над цифрой стрелочка, а под нижней стрелочкой - галочка. Вы не туда нажимали. )

Comment: Хотел побурчать насчёт поиска в списке за O(n), увидел рядом `Console.WriteLine` и успокоился :)

Answer (score 2):

В качестве варианта решения @aepot, если вы работаете на современной версии C# (9+)*, подойдёт такой компактный вариант:

```cs
foreach (var item in figure)
    if (item is Line or Ring or Square or Rectangle or Circle or Сircumference)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Такой трюк делает виртуальный вызов `ToString` через ссылку на базовый класс, и будет работать в нормальном случае, если у вас нету перегруженного `ToString()` (`new`). С `override` будет работать в любом случае.

Есть подозрения, что вам в реальности вовсе не нужна проверка типа, и вам достаточно простого кода с неявным виртуальным вызовом `ToString`:

```cs
foreach (var item in figure)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

---

Если же вам реально нужно «достучаться» до перегруженного `ToString()`, можно использовать `Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)item).ToString())`. Расходами на `dynamic` по сравнению со скоростью ввода-вывода вполне можно пренебречь.

Но более хорошей идеей является никогда не перегружать `ToString`, а только переопределять (то есть, нужно использовать `override` вместо `new`).

---

*Если у вас не .NET 5, то можно просто прописать в `.csproj`-файле `<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>` в верхней `PropertyGroup`.